# python argparse file extension checking

Tags: python, argparse

can `argparse` be used to validate filename extensions for a filename cmd line parameter?

e.g. if i have a python script i run from the cmd line:

```
$ script.py file.csv
$ script.py file.tab
$ script.py file.txt
```

i would like argparse to accept the 1st two filename cmd line options but reject the 3rd

i know you can do something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("fn", choices=["csv","tab"])
args = parser.parse_args()
```

to specify two valid choices for a cmd line option

what i'd like is this:

```
parser.add_argument("fn", choices=["*.csv","*.tab"])
```

to specify two valid file extensions for the cmd line option. Unfortunately this doesn't work - is there a way to achieve this using `argparse`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure -- you just need to specify an appropriate function as the `type`.

```
import argparse
import os.path

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

def file_choices(choices,fname):
    ext = os.path.splitext(fname)[1][1:]
    if ext not in choices:
       parser.error("file doesn't end with one of {}".format(choices))
    return fname

parser.add_argument('fn',type=lambda s:file_choices(("csv","tab"),s))

parser.parse_args()
```

demo:

```
temp $ python test.py test.csv
temp $ python test.py test.foo
usage: test.py [-h] fn
test.py: error: file doesn't end with one of ('csv', 'tab')
```

---

Here's a possibly more clean/general way to do it:

```
import argparse
import os.path

def CheckExt(choices):
    class Act(argparse.Action):
        def __call__(self,parser,namespace,fname,option_string=None):
            ext = os.path.splitext(fname)[1][1:]
            if ext not in choices:
                option_string = '({})'.format(option_string) if option_string else ''
                parser.error("file doesn't end with one of {}{}".format(choices,option_string))
            else:
                setattr(namespace,self.dest,fname)

    return Act

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('fn',action=CheckExt({'csv','txt'}))

print parser.parse_args()
```

The downside here is that the code is getting a bit more complicated in some ways -- The upshot is that the interface gets a good bit cleaner when you actually go to format your arguments.

Comment: Ummmm.... an input name of `notcsv` would not be correct? this also depends on `parser` as a global, while I think raising the exception is the correct way...

Comment: I thought of that ... but I wanted to keep the example simple ... I suppose you could do `file_choices(('.csv', '.tab))` and that's pretty good. or you could change the check to `if ext not in choices` with `ext` being `os.path.splitext(fname)[1]` or whatever ...

Comment: Jon Clements and mgilson answers look similar now - is there an advantage to using lambda here? - it seems to appear slightly more complex than the equivalent answer from Jon

Comment: I would say the main difference is that this method requires `parser` to be a global variables within scope of the function (as it uses `parser.error` - I've avoided this and raised the exception from the module instead...

Comment: @Hiett -- It allows me to use the same function to check multiple commandline arguments (e.g. if you had one where you needed to check for `.txt` or `.csv` and another where you wanted to check for `.xls` or `.doc` -- Otherwise, there's not much of a difference.

Comment: @JonClements -- Yeah.  requiring the closure around `parser` is a bit annoying -- but for the end user it's probably nicer to look at than a traceback.  I suppose, if I was writing a library to do this sort of thing, I would create a function which returns an `argparse.Action` -- That way you implicitly have a handle on the parser, but it's a lot more code for a simple task as well ...

Comment: @mgilson that's true as well I guess... ;) Who wants to write another answer to go definitive? :)

Comment: @JonClements -- I wrote it up.  Why not?

Answer (score 9):

Define a custom function which takes the name as a string - split the extension off for comparison and just return the string if it's okay, otherwise raise the exception that argparse expects:

```
def valid_file(param):
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(param)
    if ext.lower() not in ('.csv', '.tab'):
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('File must have a csv or tab extension')
    return param
```

And then use that function, such as:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename', type=valid_file)
```

Comment: so you would call valid_file just before parser.parse_args()?

Answer (score -3):

No. You can provide a container object to choices argument, or anything that supports the "in" operator. You can read more at [pydocs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#choices)

You can always check it yourself and provide feedback to the user though.