# What is the best way to "force" users to use a certain file extension with argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, file-extension

I have a script which users include the pathnames for the input and output files.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("i", help = "input path")
parser.add_argument("o", help = "output path")
args = parser.parse_args()
file_input = args.input
file_output = args.output
```

Now, I want to make sure that users create an output file that is a text file, with extension `.txt`.

(1) I could possible through an error, telling users that they *must* use a txt extension.

(2) I could check whether a `.txt` extension has been used. If not, I would simply add it.

The first is relatively easy:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("i", help = "input path")
parser.add_argument("o", help = "output path")
args = parser.parse_args()
file_input = args.input
file_output = args.output
if file_output.endswith("txt") != True:
    raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('File must end in extension .txt!')
```

How would one accomplish the latter?

Comment: `if not file_output.endswith('.txt'):  file_output += '.txt'`?

Comment: Other than `file_output += '.txt'`?

Comment: Take a look at [this quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203829/python-argparse-file-extension-checking), I think it's similar to yours.

Comment: `os.path.splitext` https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext

Comment: Or just have the tool produce output on standard input like many an honest to `$dmr` command-line tool, and let users take care of redirecting it where they want.

Comment: @sberry I think I'm following you, but how would you implement the above in an "argparse" way?

Comment: Why force it to have the `.txt` extension? File extensions are hints, not requirements; even on Windows, you can stick whatever you want in a file of whatever extension you like. Sure, the file type registrations might not work if you write the complete contents of Moby Dick to a `.jpg` file, but hey, that's your problem. I could see adding the `.txt` yourself if you want to be pushy and the user omitted it, but otherwise, let them name it what they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a `type` function that adds the required extension, e.g.

```
def txtname(astr):
    if not astr.endswith('.txt'):
        astr += '.txt'
    return astr

In [724]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [725]: parser.add_argument('-i',type=txtname);
In [726]: parser.add_argument('-o',type=txtname);
In [728]: parser.parse_args(['-i','inname','-o','oname.txt'])
Out[728]: Namespace(i='inname.txt', o='oname.txt')
```

That function could also raise a ValueError if you don't like certain extensions or forms of filename.